# How can I use Stripe Checkout with dynamic prices?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for payment on a page.  There are three items on the page and each one has a price that is set dynamically based on inputs on the page.  Let's call them plan A, B and C.  I have Stripe Checkout working successfully with a hard-coded price but I need to pass the price to Stripe based on which button is clicked and the value of that item.

PHP:

```
<?php require_once('/stripe/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('TEST KEY');

$session = new \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [[
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'product_data' => [
          'name' => 'Insurance Plan',
        ],
        'unit_amount' => 4000, //need to set this dynamically
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  ]);
?>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('PUB KEY');
    jQuery('.checkout-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var price = jQuery(this).find('.price').val(); //need to do something like this
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: "<?php echo $session->id; ?>"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Essentially, I need to create a $post request on button click that hits another file (checkout.php) and in that file, I will create the session after I have set the variable for price using the $post data.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: nth-child's link to ad-hoc pricing is no longer valid. Here is the current live link to Stripe's ad-hoc pricing documentation:
[https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices#ad-hoc-prices](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices#ad-hoc-prices)

Answer (score 16):

Eureka!  Here is the solution for anyone else who stumbles upon this issue which is not documented at all on Stripe's website.

charge.php file

```
require_once('./php/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test');

$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name = $content['name'];
$amount = intval($content['amount']*100);

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [[
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'product_data' => [
          'name' => $name,
        ],
        'unit_amount' => $amount,
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  ]);

echo json_encode($session);
```

Javascript

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test');

    jQuery('.checkout-button').on('click', function() {
        $name = jQuery(this).prev().prev().prev().text();
        $amount = jQuery(this).prev().find('.dollar-amount').text();
      fetch('/charge.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: $name,
            amount: $amount
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(session) {
        console.log(session);
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          alert(result.error.message);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', error);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

For people using Node.js:

```
stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  customer: stripeCustomerId,
  mode: data.mode,
  payment_method_types: [
    'card',
  ],
  success_url: `${MY_DOMAIN}/admin/stripe`,
  cancel_url: `${MY_DOMAIN}/admin/stripe`,
  line_items: [ // all arguments are required
    {
      price_data: {
        unit_amount: 4000,
        currency: 'usd',
        product_data: {
          name: 'Test Product'
        },
      },
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
})
```

You can read more about Ad-hoc prices [here](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices#ad-hoc-prices). You can also pass `price_data` into the Checkout, Invoice Items, and Subscription Schedule APIs.

### Update: July 2022

The link to Stripe docs was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the Checkout session during the page render, you'll need to defer that until your customer clicks one of your buttons. You'll make a request from your front end to your server to create the session then with the variable amount, return the session to the client and redirect.

Effectively its the same flow, you'll just replace that `4000` value with a value to provide in a request.

You can see an example of this (though using a Python server) in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2SmLzQ5kfY), or compare to this [PHP example](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/without-webhooks/server/php/public/pay.php#L40) of [passing a payment amount](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/without-webhooks/client/web/script.js#L102-L108) (this is not using Checkout, but the server request pattern is analogous). In your case you would pass would like `body: JSON.stringify({amount: 1234})`  and access it with `$body -> amount` to the server if the "items" pattern doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you but still struggling with this...am I doing something unorthodox that there isn't any documentation for my specific use case?  I would think this is pretty standard.  How do I get that data to JSON without a page reload?

Comment: It's not a page reload, it's an async server request from the client. The latter two links point to an example of this showing the client JS code and the server PHP to access the JSON body. If you have any other requests to your server from user actions this would function with the same ideas.

Comment: Nolan thank you for your help so far.  This got me digging down the right path.  Essentially, I need to create a $post request on button click that hits another file (checkout.php) and in that file, I will create the session after I have set the variable for price using the $post data.  I have done something like this before with ajax but I was pulling the info back into the page.  This is confusing to me bc it's running a script on that checkout.php file and then redirecting right to the checkout on Stripe.